# "pip install models": Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pip, model

For a deep-learning project, I was trying to import the 'models' library. But it's not installed on my colab notebook. So, I tried `pip install models` to install the library but it shows error which is as on the screenshot. I've also read somewhere that the library is renamed as 'pymodels'. I've also tried it but still not working.

[image]

I would be thankful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Run `pip install models -vvv` and add the full command output to the question.

Comment: @hoefling I don't think the user wants this `models`; I suspect he wants Tensorflow models. Meanwhile the package `models` doesn't have downloadable files at PyPI. It was renamed 3 or 4 times (I lost count); try to follow the renames at PyPI. The last release of the last rename I found was rolled out in 2013. All homepages of all renamed packages at Bitbucket were removed…

Comment: `Models` is not a python package, it might be python file containing model. Keep the models file in same directory and import it. Thanks!